# Зачем нужен файл .a / .lib для подключения dll?

Tags: dll, gcc, codeblocks

Для сборки программы, к которой статически прилинкована .dll, оказалось достаточно такой команды:

```
$(CC) bin\main.o -L.\bin -lcompare -o program.exe
```

При этом на момент сборки в папке `bin` должна лежать `compare.dll`. Но если я то же самое делаю из CodeBlocks, то чтобы статически слинковать dll, мне необходимо добавить в параметры линкера файл `compare.a`, который получается при сборке .dll. Почему среде разработки недостаточно просто .dll, если голый компилятор это проглатывает?

Кроме того, мне попадался вот такой пример команды сборки dll:

```
gcc -shared -o tst.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libtstdll.a dllfct.o
```

Я так понимаю, эта команда, помимо dll, генерирует файл `libtstdll.a`. Зачем это делается через -Wl? Мы же и так просто линкуем файлы, `dllfct.o` ведь уже собран? Правильно ли я понимаю, что файл `libtstdll.a` после этого можно просто прилинковать к программе безо всяких `-lmyldll`?

Answer (score 4):

Вы что то путаете, DLL вообще нельзя прилинковать статически. Первая команда указывает компилятору искать файл libcompare.a или libcompare.dll и слинковаться либо статически, либо динамически (в зависимости от того, что найдено).

Файл с расширением a или lib, который генерируется с параметром`-Wl,--out-implib` - это библиотека импорта, содержит информацию об экспортируемых функциях DLL. GCC, в отличие от MSVC, поддерживает прямую линковку с DLL без необходимости подкладывания библиотеки импорта, поэтому он вам, скорее всего, не нужен.

Если же вас интересует, зачем вообще придумана концепция "библиотека импорта", то причина, я думаю, в скорости. Куда быстрее обработать маленький файл с перечнем функций, чем парсить всю DLL и выцеплять его оттуда.

Comment: Я ничего не путаю, статическая линковка - это когда программа не может без dll, dll подключается опциями сборки, а динамическая - это когда программа вызывает `LoadLibrary`. При динамической линковке никаких специальных телодвижений для подключения dll не требуется вообще.

Comment: @Modus вы все же путаете, или по крайней мере, используете нестандартную терминологию. То, о чем вы пишете, обычно называют явное / неявное связывание (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/784bt7z7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), как разные виды динамического. Статической связывание - это включение самого тела библиотеки в исполняемый файл.

Comment: В mingw есть программа dllexport.exe (пишу по памяти название), вот codeblock использует ее для добывания связывающей .а библиотеки из указанной длл.